# How can I extract .rar file in my SD card?

Tags: openvpn

I have downloaded a VPN configuration file in .rar format but i can't extract it in my SD card. I tried Andro Zip and WinRar app for this purpose but still I can't do it. It only opens the files and not extracting it.

Comment: I have ES file explorer but it only extracts zip files and not .rar files.

Comment: It must be the reason why I fall back to ZArchiver, since ES only limits to zip,7z,gz and I'll be removing the previous one since its no useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an official .rar extractor https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rarlab.rar which is produced by the inventor of RAR.

And it's also the only(?) legitimate one to make RAR archives.

P.S. I'm not sure whether your 'WinRAR' is this 'RAR for Android'. If yes, try to get the latest version from Google Play.

Answer (score 2):

Try **Root Explorer**. Navigate to the path where the .zip file is present and long press on it. There will be an option called *Extract All*. Click it, and its done...! Your .zip files will get extracted at sdcard/SpeedSoftware.

Answer (score 0):

Attach the phone to computer and then extract it over the card.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en)
This app will solve your problem.

Just Select the file and Destination and its done.

It has also the feature of ROOT Browsing.

Comment: I have ES file explorer but it does not allow to extract or view .rar files. It supports .zip, 7z and gz files only.